# Error logic on load objects on ArrayList (The list has multiple objects with the same data)

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object, arraylist

I'm building a object list to load on database. I ran my code and realized that only one object was being persisted.

After debug I realized that my code was loading the first object on the list and then cloning the others objects on the list. On the final list, I was getting a list of the same data loaded (the arraylist finishes with multiple objects with the sabe data).
My code.

```
...
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS");
ArrayList<MyObject> MyObjectList= new ArrayList<MyObject>();
MyObject myObject= new MyObject();
String line;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            result = line.split("\\;");
            try {
                myObject.setDate(f.parse(result[0]));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            myObject.setPar1(result[1]);
            myObject.setPar2(result[2]);
            myObject.setPar3(result[3]);
            myObject.setPar4(result[4]);

            myObjectList.add(myObject);

            loadMyObjectListToDatabase(myObjectList);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are just updating and adding the same object in the loop, move the object creation inside the loop like:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      MyObject myObject= new MyObject();
      ......
  }
```